# Only minimizers of quadratic penalized least squares can be linear

Tags: least-squares, entropy, regularization

### Question

Define the matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$, the vector $b \in \mathbb{R}^m$, and the function $\mathrm{pen}: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$. Then, put the minimizer $$\hat{x} = \arg\min_{x \in \mathbb{R}^n} \|b - A x\|_2^2 + \mathrm{pen}(x).$$ I seek to understand the claim that

> We can express the minimizer $\hat{x} = C b$ for some matrix $C$ (which does not depend on $b$) only if the objective $\|b - A x\|_2^2 + \mathrm{pen}(x)$ is quadratic.

### Partial converse

Supposing that we can express $\|b - A x\|_2^2 + \mathrm{pen}(x)$ as a quadratic so that we can write $$\|b - A x\|_2^2 + \mathrm{pen}(x) = \|b_2 - A_2 x\|_2^2 + c_2$$ for some $b_2, A_2,$ and $c_2$, we see that we can express $\hat{x}$ as being a linear function of $b_2$. Assuming $b_2$ is a linear function of $b$,  the conclusion follows.

## (Partial) Counterexample

Let $f$ be any function which is minimized at the origin $0$ and $K$ be an arbitrary conformable matrix. Then, the minimizer $$\arg\min_{x \in \mathbb{R}^n} \left\{ \|b-Ax\|_2^2 + \left( f\left(x - Kb \right) - \|b-Ax\|_2^2 \right) \right\}$$ is a linear function of $b$ while the penalty needn't create a quadratic objective.

For instance, consider $f = \|\cdot\|$ to be some norm. Then,
\begin{align*}
 & \arg\min_{x \in \mathbb{R}^n} \left\{ \|b-Ax\|_2^2 + \left( f\left(x - Kb \right) - \|b-Ax\|_2^2 \right) \right\} \\
 = \, & \arg\min_{x \in \mathbb{R}^n} f\left(x - Kb \right) \\
 = \, & Kb,
\end{align*} 
which is a linear function of $b$ produced by the penalty $f\left(x - Kb \right) - \|b-Ax\|_2^2$.

This may be an objectionable counter example since the penalty depends on $A$ and $b$. I can't currently find a counterexample without this dependence (ie a nontrivial counterexample.)

## Proof (in convex case)

Suppose that $\mathrm{pen}$ is convex. Suppose further than $\mathrm{pen}$ does not depend on $A$ or $b$. From the first order condition, we see that $0 = 2A^T (b - A \hat{x}) + \hat{z},$ or $$A^T A \hat{x} + \frac{1}{2} \hat{z} = A^T b,$$ where $\hat{x}$ is the minimizer and $\hat{z}$ is in the subgradient at $\hat{x}$. From the latter supposition, we know that $\hat{x}$ will be a linear function of $b$ if and only if $\hat{z}$ is a linear function of $\hat{x}$. Therefore it follows that $\mathrm{pen}$ is a quadratic (or linear or constant) function of $\hat{x}$, making the objective quadratic.

Since this is the setting of the paper in the motivation section linked below, I suspect that this is the likely answer.

## Motivation

The paper

> D. L. Donoho, I. M. Johnstone, J. C. Hoch, and a S. Stern, “Maximum Entropy and the Nearly Black Object,” J. R. Stat. Soc. Ser. B Methodol., vol. 54, no. 1, pp. 41–81, 1992.

contains on the bottom of page 3 the sentence (with slightly different notation)

> because the objective is not quadratic, the minimizer is not linear in the observations vector $b$.

Perhaps another result was meant under some other conditions that the entropy satisfies.

Comment: Could you explain how you know your counterexample minimizer is a linear function of $b$?

Comment: @whuber Thanks! I've clarified that "(Partial) counterexample" section and included another section "(Partial) proof".